# "Не... не..." или "ни... ни..." c глаголами. Какие частицы следует использовать в двустишии?

Tags: частица-не, частица, поэзия, не-с-глаголом

Вопрос касательно использования "не... не..." и "ни... ни..." c глаголами.
Какие частицы следует использовать в приведенном ниже двустишии?

> Ни подвигом, ни словом
>   Не разжечь, не покорить

или

> Ни подвигом, ни словом
>   Ни разжечь, ни покорить

Сам считаю, что грамматически верным будет первый вариант.
Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 5):

Перечисляемые "ни" здесь можно заменить - мысленно - на "и", ведь частица "ни" усилительная. В отличие от "не" - отрицательной, в нашем случае - отрицающей следующий за ней глагол.

Так что верен первый вариант:

*Ни подвигом, ни словом*

*Не разжечь, не покорить.*

---

[ПРАВОПИСАНИЕ ЧАСТИЦ НЕ и НИ](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.58)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Очень помогли!

Comment: Присоединяюсь к орфографическому выводу и апвоутирую. Но уж больно разнородные сущности здесь объединены - так и подмывает дополнить этот текст до четверостишия добавлением чего-то семантически равноценного:
_Ни подвигом, ни словом
Не разжечь, не покорить;
Ни сапогом, ни пловом
Не растоптать, не накормить._

Comment: Сашко, шикарно!